# flippant.js does not pull html. Displays [object HTMLDivElement] instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, flippant

I am attempting to create a modal that flips. The front modal displays fine however the back modal just displays [object HTMLDivElement] instead of displaying the modal.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#introModal').modal('show');
    window.onload = function () {
    function flip() {

        var front = document.getElementById('introModal');
        var back_content = document.getElementById('backModal'); // Generate or pull any HTML you want for the back.
        var back;

        // when the correct action happens, call flip!
        back = flippant.flip(front, back_content)
        // this creates the back element, sizes it and flips it around.

        // call the close method on the back element when it's time to close.
    }

    document.getElementById('testbutton').onclick = flip;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then extract html for it :)

```
var back_content = $('#backModal').html()
```

or

```
var back_content = document.getElementById('backModal').innerHTML;
```

or

```
var back_content = document.getElementById('backModal').outerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank You, so why is it not required above? Thats where I did not follow? Shouldn't this line: var front = document.getElementById('introModal'); have needed the .innerHTML as well?

Comment: I guess no. Front should have already been inside the DOM. While backface is something that is append afterwards.